# Filtering jobs for minimum salary includes some jobs without salary information

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm filtering [jobs in Berlin, with a minimum salary of 1 Euros](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?l=berlin&d=20&u=Km&s=1&c=EUR&sort=p). I expect to see only job offers where a salary range is provided. This is mostly the case, but some ads without salary information have made it into the results somehow. For example:

[image]

The same happens when I add `salary:1eur..` to the search query.

Is this a bug or is my expectation of behavior unfounded?

Comment: Für einen Euro gibt's in Berlin ja immerhin schonmal eine Currywurst! :)